# How do I check for null in case of a SQL Server function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scalar function that returns an email address if the user exists and returns null if the user doesn't exist.

I need to call this function from a stored procedure and the stored procedure needs to return the email address if the user exists and it should return "User doesn't exist" if he doesn't.

The problem I'm facing is how do I check for null in the case of a function? Or am I looking at this the wrong way? A code snippet is given below of what I'm looking for. An IF EXISTS wouldn't work in this instance. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Alter procedure [dbo].[xalumniGetPrimaryEmailAddress] 
@login varchar(50) 
AS

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (select dbo.ZAlumniGetPrimaryAddress(@login))

    BEGIN
        PRINT @login+' EXISTS'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT @login+' DOES NOT EXIST'
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Alter procedure [dbo].[xalumniGetPrimaryEmailAddress] 
      @login varchar(50) 
      AS

 BEGIN
 IF dbo.ZAlumniGetPrimaryAddress(@login) is not null

     BEGIN
         PRINT @login+' EXISTS'
     END
      ELSE
     BEGIN
         PRINT @login+' DOES NOT EXIST'
     END
 END
 GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
IsNull(dbo.ZAlumniGetPrimaryAddress(@login), 'User does not exist')
```

Or:

```
Coalesce(dbo.ZAlumniGetPrimaryAddress(@login), 'User does not exist')
```

Does that help?